# Unittest equality of two nested dictionaries

Tags: python, unit-testing, dictionary

Which `assert` statement should I use, if  I want to compare 2 dicts that have a `list` of values inside them.

For example, if these dicts are like this:

```
{'other_parts': ['director', 'head', 'chief', 'leader', 'administrator'], 'headword': 'manager', 'language': 'en'}

{'other_parts': ['director', 'chief', 'head', 'leader', 'administrator'], 'headword': 'manager', 'language': 'en'}
```

I want comparison of these two dicts to pass, because I don't care about order in nested list.
Comparison with `assertDictEqual` fails, because nested lists of `other_parts` are not in the same order, I presume.

Comment: To understand: Order within the list does is irrelevant, but an element might appear a different number of times in each list, in which case they are considered different?

Comment: @Mike :
Final list of `other_parts` will not contain duplicates.
The first example is there just because it confused me by passing.

Comment: So in that case, I would have changed the question to describe your exact needs - otherwise, answers will be irrelevant for your specific issue.

Comment: @Mike you're right, I've edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't care about order, you'll have to sort the lists or use a set (only if you're sure the lists won't contain duplicates!)

```
dict1['other_parts'] = sorted(dict1['other_parts'])
dict2['other_parts'] = sorted(dict2['other_parts'])
assertDictEqual(dict1, dict2)
```

which can also be used as

```
from unittest import TestCase
TestCase().assertEqual(dict1, dict2)
```

See docs : https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.addTypeEqualityFunc

Answer (score 2):

After revising your question, it seems that `AssertCountEqual` is what you are looking for - it does exactly that, as explained in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertCountEqual).
If it does not work for the whole structure, I would have run it on each inner list using a loop.